# Programmatically Add a AnnotationSessionFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, runtime

I have a class that implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.

I am trying to add an AnnotationSessionFactoryBean to my Spring Context in either postProcessBeanFactory or postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry.  I need to do this programmatically so that I can configure the object at runtime.

I am trying to do:

```
@Override
public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry bdr) throws BeansException {

RootBeanDefinition bd = new RootBeanDefinition(
AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.class);

            // fails here.. can not cast
 AnnotationSessionFactoryBean asfb = (AnnotationSessionFactoryBean)bd;

 bdr.registerBeanDefinition("sessionFactory", asfb);
```

---

--updated with solution:

had to do a:

```
    GenericBeanDefinition bd = new GenericBeanDefinition();
    bd.setBeanClass(AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.class);
    bd.getPropertyValues().add("dataSource", dataSource);
            bdr.registerBeanDefinition("sessionFactory", bd);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bean definition is *not* the actual bean, so you can't cast.

Use GenericBeanDefinition instead of RootBeanDefinition. Then you can use the `propertyValues` of the bean definition to set the required beans for AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.

This way, you can do something like the following before the calling registerBeanDefinition():

```
bd.getPropertyValues().add("dataSource", dataSource);
bd.getPropertyValues().add("annotatedClasses", listOfClasses);
etc...
```

Note that if you run into issues where dataSource or other properties are not yet defined, you can use a `RuntimeBeanReference` instead as a placeholder by doing something like `bd.getPropertyValues().add("dataSource", new RuntimeBeanReference("dataSource")`.